# Batch Print email attachments in order by date

Tags: vba, email, printing, outlook

**Issue:**

Hello, I have a macro, which saves me for a lot of clicking, but in the end not so much time, when it all comes down to it. The code allows me to mark everything within any mail folder. It will print the attachments within the email.

After this the error starts. Whenever I press this button, the items are ready and set to go, for a race to the printer. Meaning that whatever attachment that gets to the printer first, is the one that gets printed first. I then have to put everything in the right order when it has been printed.

**My current code:**

```
Sub BatchPrintAllAttachmentsinMultipleEmails()
    Dim objFileSystem As Object
    Dim strTempFolder As String
    Dim objSelection As Outlook.Selection
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
    Dim objAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim objShell As Object
    Dim objTempFolder As Object
    Dim objTempFolderItem As Object
    Dim strFilePath As String

    Set objFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    strTempFolder = objFileSystem.GetSpecialFolder(2).Path & "\Temp for Attachments " & Format(Now, "YYYY-MM-DD_hh-mm-ss")
    'Create a new temp folder
    MkDir (strTempFolder)

    Set objSelection = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection

    For Each objItem In objSelection
        If TypeOf objItem Is MailItem Then
           Set objMail = objItem
           Set objAttachments = objMail.Attachments

           'Save all the attachments in the temp folder
           For Each objAttachment In objAttachments
               strFilePath = strTempFolder & "\" & objAttachment.FileName
               objAttachment.SaveAsFile (strFilePath)

               'Print all the files in the temp folder
               Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
               Set objTempFolder = objShell.NameSpace(0)
               Set objTempFolderItem = objTempFolder.ParseName(strFilePath)
               objTempFolderItem.InvokeVerbEx ("print")
           Next objAttachment
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**Goal:**

I would like the code to look for dates, and print the oldest first, and work its way up for the newest date. Is there by any chance, that I can put in a string, which gets the macro to "cool down" and send it to the printer in order, by the oldest date to the newest?

Comment: Sort items `Items.Sort "[ReceivedTime]"` then use reverse loop `For i = Items.Count To 1 Step -1`

Comment: Should I then get rid of the Shell verb? And where would you implement this in my code to get it to work?